# how to use a .properties file value with " " with in " "?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to add a functionality in existing projcet if value is found then use

`System.setProperty("javaplugin.vm.options","-Xmx512m");`

Actually i am getting value -Xmx512m through a variable say a. so how to write this statement

`System.setProperty("javaplugin.vm.options",""Xmx"");`

I tried to search it on google but din't find it..... Anyone please suggest... Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't get it, you mean that the variable `a` holds 512? can't you do this: `int a = 512;` `System.setProperty("javaplugin.vm.options","Xmx" + a + "m");`?

Answer (score 4):

You should try

```
System.setProperty("javaplugin.vm.options","\"-Xmx512m\"");
```

With the `\`, you can escape the double quotes in Strings so that they appear as double quotes.